# Failed to install app in physical device through XCode 13.2.1

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, certificate-signing-request

Our provision certificates expired last week, we have created the latest and downloaded all in our Xcode project.
After that, we tried automatic signing and manual signing; however, both of them are not working when we are trying to install app in physical device.
xCODE: 13.2.1 And iPhone: 15.1
XCode gives error, unable to install appName with below details:

Unable to install "ZigBank" Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402620395 User Info: {   DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-11 07:55:57 +0000";   IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher; }

A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402620395 User Info: {   DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;   MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008015)";   "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = ( 0  DTDeviceKitBase           0x0000000118f0abec DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272 1  DTDeviceKitBase           0x0000000118f463f4 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160 2  DVTFoundation            0x000000010272b964 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76 3  DTDeviceKitBase           0x0000000118f46144 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1312 4  IDEiOSSupportCore          0x000000011e4dfa60 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 2908 5  DVTFoundation            0x0000000102856684 DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK + 16 6  DVTFoundation            0x0000000102857c70 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 564 7  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001c18925f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 8  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001c18941b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 9  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001c189b8a8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 10 libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001c189c404 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 11 libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001c18a6c98 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 12 libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001c1a54360 _pthread_wqthread + 288 13 libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001c1a53080 start_wqthread + 8 ); }

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {   "device_model" = "iPhone14,3";   "device_osBuild" = "15.1.1 (19B81)";   "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";   "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;   "launchSession_state" = 1;   "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;   "operation_duration_ms" = 29447;   "operation_errorCode" = "-402620395";   "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";   "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;   "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;   "param_consoleMode" = 0;   "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;   "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;   "param_debugger_type" = 5;   "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;   "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";   "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;   "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;   "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;   "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;   "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;   "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;   "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;   "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;   "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;   "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;   "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;   "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;   "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;   "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;   "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;   "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;   "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;   "param_install_style" = 0;   "param_launcher_UID" = 2;   "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;   "param_launcher_kind" = 0;   "param_launcher_style" = 0;   "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;   "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;   "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";   "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";   "param_runnable_type" = 2;   "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;   "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;   "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;   "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.2";   "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";   "sdk_variant" = iphoneos; }

Comment: What do you see when you log in to http://developer.apple.com and http://appstoreconnect.apple.com ? Sometimes it's just a matter of agreeing to new terms.

Comment: No, it's not  a case